# How do I transform a mesh to have exact angles between two faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, measurement

I am a brand new user to Blender and am having difficulty finding a way to "set" angles between faces for a mesh I am transforming. Currently, the angles are off very slightly, and I have been manually trying to transform it until I can get the correct angle. I was able to get close with angles 80.541, and 116.513, but they need to be 85.0 and 116.5 exactly. When trying to explicitly set the XYZ values by typing in a number in the Transform Controls, the angle measurements disappear which makes it difficulty to know if I have gotten the correct angle until I select the face again. Thank you very much for the help!

Here is what I have currently:

[image: Current model]

Comment: Hi. If you activate the built-in addon MeasureIt Tools, you can measure the angles to 5 decimal places. These measurements do not disappear when you are trying to set the angle. Thus, you can see to set them to 85.00000 degrees and 116.50000 degrees.

Comment: Apart from using the _MeasureIt_ tool, I would be able to create this manually, the question would be: you said the angles need to be 85° and 116.5°, but how exact do you need the other components? Side lengths, the other angles...? Of course with given angles some values mathematically just result from this premise, so I ask are there more requirements?

Comment: The MeasureIt addon worked perfectly and helped quite a bit. It still is very time consuming without being able to somehow set the angles and lengths of everything. @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for your offer, however I will potentially have 50+ different sizes I will need to make for this. I have all the measurements of all sides, angles, and thicknesses, but getting them into blender exactly has been a challenge for me so far.